# How can write test for laravel api route with auth.basic middleware

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-dusk

My laravel project has an API route by auth.basic middleware which is used id of the authenticated user in the controller. when I call it in postman it works well and I get 401 when the username or password is incorrect, but in laravel APITest which extends from DuskTestCase, authentication does not take place so I get 500 instead of 401 when the user's informations were incorrect. However, by correct information, I have the same error because auth() is null.

it is written like below, which is wrong?

api.php route:

```
Route::get('/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx', 'xxxxx@xxxx')->middleware('auth.basic');
```

APITest:

```
$response = $this->withHeaders(['Authorization' => 'Basic '. base64_encode("{$username}:{$password}")])->get("/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `actingAs()` method for authentication in tests.

An example from docs:

```
public function testApplication()
{
    $user = factory(App\User::class)->create();

    $this->actingAs($user)
         ->withSession(['foo' => 'bar'])
         ->visit('/')
         ->see('Hello, '.$user->name);
}
```

Another example that you can use for an API:

```
    $user = User::factory()->create();

    $response = $this->actingAs($user)->json('GET', $this->uri);

    $response->assertOk();
```

For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#sessions-and-authentication

Comment: Thanks, it works, and controller access to the user's authentication data when using actingAs($user).